# How to get the array of a 2d array in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have this model,

```
function getData($id)
{
    $arr=array(array());
    $sql = "SELECT ID, title FROM topic WHERE ....";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($id));
    $arr[0][0] = $query->result();
    $sql = "SELECT ID, title FROM topic WHERE ....";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,array($id));
    $arr[0][1] = $query->result();
    return $arr;
}
```

And in my Controller, 
I have this code,

```
$data['check'] = $this->Model->getData("21313");
...
$this->load->view('check',$data);
```

How can I echo all the data?

I tried,

```
foreach($check[0][0] as $row)
{
    echo $row->ID;
    echo $row->title;
}
```

But it is not working.

Comment: _Not working_ you say... That's interesting.

Comment: And which framework do you use?

Comment: @rizier123, codeigniter

Comment: Why you were getting values within two different arrays why don't you get it within one. Whats your query? post your query and result and instead of using `$query->result()` try `$query->result_array()`

Answer (score 0):

try to `print_r($data);` first on your **controller**

and then check the structure if `$check` is your model result you can do this on your **view**

```
foreach($check as $row)
{
    echo $row->ID;
    echo $row->title;
}
```

Comment: it prints Array ( [0] => Array ( ) )

Comment: means no result in your return of getData function in your model

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$data['check'] = $this->Model->getData("21313");
    //you can check your data by
    var_dump($data);die;
```